# a function that takes a list value and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def comma(list_1):
    n = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))

    # iterating till the range
    for i in range(0, n):
        element = input('Add element')
        list_1.append(element)  # adding the element

    list_str = f'{list_1[1:len(list_1)-1]} and {list_1[-1]}'
    print(list_str)
    return list_str


list_2 = []
comma(list_2)
```

My question is how do I convert the list slice in my f string to a string so when I print the list so it appears as a string concatenated with the remainder of the f string.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a list to a string, first make an empty string and then add each item, plus a comma and space to the string.

```
string = ''
for i in list_1:
string += i + ', '
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
", ".join(map(str, lst[:-1])) + f" and {lst[-1]}"
```

For example:

```
lst = [3,4,5,6,7]
result = ", ".join(map(str, lst[:-1])) + f" and {lst[-1]}"
print(result) # 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7
```

If your values are strings then you simply need to do this:

```
", ".join(lst[:-1]) + f" and {lst[-1]}"
```

Example:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
result = ", ".join(lst[:-1]) + f" and {lst[-1]}"
print(result) # a, b and c
```